# WPF MVVM - What's the most correct way to fire events within TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm currently using this extension to set specific events which handle data in the ViewModel... Example:

```
<swi:Interaction.Triggers>
    <swi:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <esi:CallDataMethod Method="SaveRevision_Clicked"/>
    </swi:EventTrigger>
</swi:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Where esi and swi are:

```
xmlns:esi="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity;assembly=Expression.Samples.Interactivity"
xmlns:swi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

But what I want to set an event for a TreeViewItem? I don't have direct access to them, do I?

EDIT: I'm actually using ItemContainerStyle,

```
<Style x:Key="FolderView" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Name="img"
                               Width="20"
                               Height="20"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill"
                               Source="Images/hdicon.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FolderName}" Margin="5,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But I can't place my event in there. Where should I put these lines?

```
<swi:Interaction.Triggers>
    <swi:EventTrigger EventName="Expanded">
        <esi:CallDataMethod Method="Expand"/>
    </swi:EventTrigger>
</swi:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TreeView.ItemContainerStyle to achive this, here are couple of implementations which may help:

[Strange Behaviour WPF TreeView ItemContainerStyle and ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622847/strange-behaviour-wpf-treeview-itemcontainerstyle-and-itemtemplate)

[WPF Double Click TreeviewItem Child Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295897/wpf-double-click-treeviewitem-child-node)

Comment: But how to set the triggers using behaviors with the Interactivity lib?

Comment: You can try this bit:
 <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >                     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>                 </Style>             </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>